# How does a One-Class SVM work?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

My teacher explained the function of a one-class SVM to us.

However, the sketch used is not correct from my point of view. I understand the function of a one-class SVM as follows:

- The SVM is trained with normal data. It finds a blue circle (in 2 dim) where most of the training data lies. However, some of the training data may lie outside, but will be penalized.
- After the SVM is trained, all data points that lie outside the blue circle are classified as anomalies. So in my opinion, the sketch should be split into two sketches. And the point that lies outside the blue circle but inside the green circle should also be classified as anomalous.

Or am I wrong?

Thank you for your help :)

Original image:
[image: Original image]

In my opinion correct:
[image: In my opinion correct]